# flex property don't resize all div according to screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

I have three icons with text in a row, each of them separated by an image of an arrow. What I want is that on **desktop** according to screen size all elements will resize themselves proportionally. To do this I use flexbox and flex property on child elements.
Problem is that only the arrow image has been resized, and not the other elements like text and icon (camera icon).
Can you help me achieve this task using flexbox (not grid)?

Render is what I want in all desktop sizes.
[image: This is how it should be on any desktop screen]

Render that I get with a smaller desktop size ( only arrow  has been resized, not camera icon and text )

[image: Bad render]

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-content">
        <div class="child">
            <img src="camera.svg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Hello</div>
            <div style="width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis temporibus ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="arrow-mb.svg">
            <source media="(min-width:481px)" srcset="arrow.svg">
            <img src="arrow.svg" alt="Arrow">
        </picture>

        <div class="child">
            <img src="camera.svg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Hello</div>
            <div style="width: 172px; margin: 0 auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis temporibus ipsum.</div>
        </div>
        <picture>
            <source media="(max-width:480px)" srcset="arrow-mb.svg">
            <source media="(min-width:481px)" srcset="arrow.svg">
            <img src="arrow.svg" alt="Arrow">
        </picture>
        <div class="child">
            <img src="camera.svg" alt="">
            <div class="title">Hello</div>
            <div style="width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa blanditiis temporibus ipsum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
<style>


    .container {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 10px;

    }

    .container-content {
        justify-content: space-around;
        display: flex;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 70%;
        align-items: center;

    }
    .container * {
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .child,
    picture {
        flex: 1;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .child .title {
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #5E6420;
        font-family: Ano Bold;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:480px) {
        picture {
            margin: 20px 0;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 0;
        }

        .container-content {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
       
    }
    
</style>
```

After answer:
Property min-width solve problem. But with different length of text, icons and title not on same line. How to conserve them on same line no matter screen sizes.

This is what I mean by not on same line:
[image: Align icon and title on same line]

Comment: try min-width:0 on child elements

Comment: @TemaniAfif In fact min-width:0 solve the problem. Can you explain why ? But now I have a problem that arose because of this property  so that if I have different size of text., icons will not be on the same line. Do you know how to solve this ? See my edit

Answer (score 1):

you have assigned fix width to the text div in your html code `<div style="width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;">` due to which the container div is also fixed at the same width.
Try using min-width & max-width instead of a fixed width.

Comment: Thanks. This solution also solve problem. But due to that property there is a problem with alignment of icon and title. I want that the text will be pushed down and icon and title will remain on same line. Can you help me fix this. See my edit

Answer (score 1):

You are not set any width for the image that's why image takes width as the default resolution. You can try like this hopefully it will work.

```
.child img{
    max-width: 100% or any other number with px;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
    .child img{
        width: any number with px;
    }
}
```

Comment: At certain point your answer hide the arrow icon. See my last picture in my post and tell me if you can help me solve this issue.